# How can I create a "Product" of a Store programatically in SocialEngine (I am having StorePlugin)

Tags: socialengine

I have Socialengine with Store Plugin....
I want to create a product in store programatically(Not using GUI and Not using Admin Panel) from an other module like events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps
 1. Get the owner_id from viewer
 2. Query for store_id from "sitestore_stores" table
 3. Create an array having all the fields like in table "sitestoreproduct_product"
 4. get the Adapter

```
$table = Engine_Api::_()->getItemTable('sitestoreproduct_product');
$db = $table->getAdapter();
$db->beginTransaction();
```

1. Create Row and set the created array and then save

   $sitestoreproduct = $table->createRow();
       $sitestoreproduct->setFromArray($values);
       $sitestoreproduct->save();
2. Finally Commit the Database.